# 'StreamSubscription<LocationData>' cannot be assigned to 'StreamSubscription<Map<String, double>>'

Tags: dart, flutter, location

Currently learning Flutter and got this error while trying to detect the location of my device:

> A value of type 'StreamSubscription' can't be assigned
>   to a variable of type 'StreamSubscription>'

I was following an online tutorial but somehow got this error.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => AppState();
} 

class AppState extends State<MainPage> {

  Map<String,double> currentLocation = new Map();
  StreamSubscription<Map<String,double>> locationSubscription;

  var location = new Location();
  String error;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    currentLocation['latitude'] = 0.0;
    currentLocation['longitude'] = 0.0;

    initPlatformState();

    locationSubscription = 
    location.onLocationChanged().listen((Map<String,double> result) {
      setState(() {
        currentLocation = result; 
      });
    });
  }

  void initPlatformState() async{
    Map<String,double> myLocation;
    try {
      myLocation = await location.getLocation();
      error="";
    } on PlatformException catch(e) {
      if(e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED')
        error = "permission denied";
      else if(e.code == "PERMISSION_DENIED_NEVER_ASK")
        error = "permission denied";
      myLocation = null;
    }

    setState(() {
      currentLocation = myLocation; 
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(""),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FlutterMap(
          options: MapOptions(
          ),
          layers: [
            TileLayerOptions(

            ),
          ]
        ),
      )
    ); 
  } 
}
```

I would be very grateful for any advice. Here is the video I followed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K4nYTayjofY&t=321s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the tutorial was done using an older version of the `location` plugin, since v2.0.0 they changed the api to return structured data rather than a map.

https://github.com/Lyokone/flutterlocation/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

So you'd need to either change all your `Map<String, double>` types to `LocationData` or set your plugin version to `^1.4.0`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried many ways till I found this way thanks to a kind person who helped on another flutter facebook group.Make sure in your pubspec.yaml you update location to the latest version

```
dependencies:
  location: ^2.3.5
```

Then change it to the following code:

```js
  LocationData _currentLocation;
  StreamSubscription<LocationData> _locationSubscription;

  var _locationService = new Location();
  String error;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    initPlatformState();

    _locationSubscription = _locationService
        .onLocationChanged()
        .listen((LocationData currentLocation) async {
      setState(() {
        _currentLocation = currentLocation;
      });
    });
  }

  void initPlatformState() async {
    try {
      _currentLocation = await _locationService.getLocation();


    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED') {
        error = 'Permission denied';
      }else if(e.code == "PERMISSION_DENIED_NEVER_ASK"){
        error = 'Permission denied';
      }
      _currentLocation = null;
    }
```

You may access longitude and latitude as

_currentLocation.longitude and _currentLocation.latitude

these will return double values. Also, there are more options available at 
https://pub.dev/packages/location#-readme-tab-